# removing word interchanged elements of list in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, data-extraction

I have a list with repeating values which have been interchanged. for example

```
dataList=["john is student", "student is john", "john student is", "john is student", "alica is student", "good weather", "weather good"]
```

I want to remove all these repeating values as shown:

expected output:

```
dataList=["john is student","john is student", "john is student","john is student","alica is student", "good weather", "good weather"]
```

the code which I am trying to  use is:

```
for i in dataList:
    first=(i.split()[0]) +  i.split()[1] + i.split()[2]) in studentList
    ........
```

I am stuck in forming a logic. May I know how I can get my required result

Comment: Your question is incomplete! ..Which to keep between `"good weather"` and `"weather good"`? I guess **the first** one?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I have mentioned that in the expected output that "good weather" is what I want. Thanks for the solution, it helped. One small update I made to my question, I want to keep the repetitive values, I do not want to remove them. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider that first occurrence is correct one that you need in the final list then you can try following:

```
dataList= ["john is student", 
           "student is john", 
           "john student is", 
           "alica is student", 
           "good weather", 
           "weather good",
          ]

data = {}
for words in dataList:
    data.setdefault(frozenset(words.split()), words)

dataList = data.values() 
 # dataList is you need
```

---

**Edit**

Since I last answer question has been updated with the requirement to keep the repetitive values.

**[Answer]**

```
dataList= ["john is student", 
           "student is john", 
           "john student is",
           "alica is student",
           "good weather", 
           "weather good",
          ]

class WordFrequence:
    def __init__(self, word, frequence=1):
        self.word = word
        self.frequence = frequence

    def as_list(self):
        return [self.word] * self.frequence

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({}, {})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.word, self.frequence)    

counter = {} 
for words in dataList:
    key = frozenset(words.split())
    if key in counter:
        counter[key].frequence += 1
    else:
        counter[key] = WordFrequence(words)

dataList = [] # this is what you need
for wf in counter.values():
    dataList.extend(wf.as_list())
```

For long input `dataList` you can improve my code by replacing `WordFrequence` with [`recordclass`](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. It helped. Since I updated my requirement in the question, so the new code would be:

data = {}
new=[]
for words in dataList:
    k=data.setdefault(frozenset(words.split()), words)
    new.append(k)
print(new)

can you please update your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Cathy added one more answer that will prevent order too. check below post

Answer (score 2):

@Grijesh has already given a very clean solution, just re-iterating his code -

```
dataList=["john is student", "student is john", "john student is", 
          "alica is student", "good weather", "weather good"]

final_data = {} 
for i in dataList:
    data[" ".join(sorted(set(i.split())))] = i
```

#### Output

```
>>>list(final_data.values())
   ['john student is', 'alica is student', 'weather good']
```

Above, we slipted the sentence to get the words, and then we created a unique word set and sorted it to capture unique instances even in sentences.

Now we made a dictionary out of it, we know that dictionary can only hold unique keys only, so it will keep only the unique sets only (to which we have made a string out finally by doing a join)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary `seen` storing `frozenset` of words for each element with the first occurrence of words. You can first check-in `seen` dict and set or get the older value using `{}.setdefault( )`.

```
dataList= ["john is student", 
           "student is john", 
           "john student is",
           "alica is student",
           "good weather", 
           "weather good",
          ]

seen = {}
data = []
for words in dataList:
    key = frozenset(words.split())
    words = seen.setdefault(key, words)
    data.append(words)
```

output:

```
>>> data
['john is student',
 'john is student',
 'john is student',
 'alica is student',
 'good weather',
 'good weather']
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the first occurrence is the correct one.

```
dataList= ["john is student", 
           "student is john", 
           "john student is", 
           "alica is student", 
           "good weather", 
           "weather good",
          ]

filterdData = {}
for statement in dataList:
    filterdData.setdefault(''.join(sorted(statement)), statement)

dataList = filterdData.values() 
print(dataList)
```

You can also wrap a grammar check library with the iterations to accept only the correct form of the English.